# how to load/steup flexlib project source in flex builder?

Tags: apache-flex

I downloaded **flexlib** source from http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/

I want to be able to set it up and run it in flex builder and play with it for learning purpose.

I tried to use the import project option by pointing to the flexlib directory but it did not work - I think thats because the source by default does not have any .project or properties files.

Visual studio projects are so simple :) - double click the .sln file and rest is taken care by god(ms).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an Import, create a new Flex Library Project.  In the **New Flex Library Project** window, change the Folder so that it is pointed to the *flexlib* source.